# Deleting a cosmosDB Item with AzureFunctions

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to implement a simple CRUD functionality with Azure Functions implemented in Java.
I am using a CosmosDB created over the Azure CLI like shown in the tutorial of Microsoft.
Accessing the CosmosDB over Input and Outputbindings to retrieve the data works, but the documentations doesn't state a way to delete an item.
Is it possible to delete an item over an Java Binding or do i have to access the database differently for a delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, Azure function Cosmos DB binging does not provide `DocumnetDBClient` usage. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#input---usage. So we need to create a client by ourselves. Then we use `deleteDocument` method to delete the item. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.documentclient.deletedocument?view=azure-java-stable